# Is there a way to convert a date as 2008.5 (the middle of the year 2008) in a proper date with excel?

Tags: excel, date

I have a series of values (concentrations of ions in the atmosphere) each plotted in function of their date that looks a little bit like this

```
+---------+----------+---------+
|  Year   | Sulphate | Nitrate |
+---------+----------+---------+
| 2008.0  | 22.8     | 12.5    |
| 2007.75 | 13.5     | 13.4    |
| 2007.5  | 10.2     | 12.7    |
| 2007.25 | 19.4     | 10.3    |
| 2007.0  | 25.4     | 12.4    |
+---------+----------+---------+
```

is there a way to convert the year in a proper date? Like, 2008 should become 01/01/2008 (first of jan of 2008) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display a proper date (middle of the year, a quarter of the year, etc.) then you can try the following formula:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),1,1)+(DATE(LEFT(A1,4)+1,1,1)-DATE(LEFT(A1,4),1,1))*MOD(A1,1)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: thanks! will it also work for different fractions as is?

Comment: Yes, it should have. For example, `2008.10` (1/10th of the year) returns the result of `06/02/2008`.

Comment: P.S. Feel free to accept one of the answers as correct if you are happy with the solution. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.

Comment: One last thing... below the year 1900 it's not working as well as after that 
(for example, the year 1895.0 i.e. 1st Jan 1985 become 3795-01-01) I'm going as low as 1100 CE, should I separate the month and day (it seems like those two are working) and then paste them again after subtracting 1900 yrs to the first 4 digits?

Comment: That's a tricky one :-) the lowest date allowed by Excel is 1st Jan 1900 and any date below that is simply not recognized. You could, of course, separate the month and day (as you suggested yourself) and then "attach" the year, but then you won't be able to format such a cell as "Date" (only Text/General would be allowed).

Comment: Ok! To be honest I am not that interested into having excel recognize it as a date because I just use it as a way to store data (the majority of the data analysis will be made in R). Thanks again!

Comment: Fair point - then you can probably use any other year in your calculation (e.g. year `2000` and replace the years afterwards, i.e. something similar to - `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(DATE(2000,1,1)+(DATE(2000,1,1)-DATE(2000,1,1))*MOD(A1,1),"dd/mm/yyyy"),2000,LEFT(A1,4))`. But you probably already have it figured out :-) take care

Answer (score 2):

Another method, that might come a bit closer:

```
=DATE(INT(A2),MOD(A2,1)*12+1,MOD(MOD(A2,1)*12,1)*30+1)
```

The formula assumes all months have 30 days.

Understand that, because months have different numbers of days, that a formula like this may not always give an "exact" result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*is there a way to convert the year in a proper date? Like, 2008 should become 01/01/2008*

Yes, with the Function DATE:

> **[DATE Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

Also with function LEFT to get the first 4 chars.

> **[LEFT Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/left-leftb-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

[image]

My formula in B2 is:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2;4);1;1)
```

Hope this helps.